# How to tell Helm which repo & chart is going to install?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm following Helm's document [here](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helm-install-installing-a-package) to install a package, a.k.a. a helm chart:

```
$ helm install happy-panda stable/mariadb
```

It's really convenient to have a ready-to-use package. But in case of a package doesn't belong to `stable` repo, for example `appmesh-grafana` then I have to do more than this:

```
$ helm repo add aws https://aws.github.io/eks-charts
$ helm install aws/appmesh-grafana --version 0.1.0
```

Therefore, it forces me surf around the internet to find repo url, package name, etc. I don't want to do it every single time!

Is there any way to specify the repo and chart to install using `Chart.yaml`? I prefer Chart.yaml than shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, if a chart is not in the official repo, then you always need to add the repository first before installing the chart.

However, starting from the Helm 3, you can look for the chart directly in the [Helm Hub](https://hub.helm.sh/). In your case, if you wanted to find `appmesh-grafana`, you can execute the following command.

```
$ helm search hub appmesh-grafana
URL                                             CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/aws/appmesh-grafana  0.1.0           6.4.3           App Mesh Grafana Helm chart for Kubernetes
```

But then, yes, you need to open the link, find the address, and anyway execute `$ helm repo add aws https://aws.github.io/eks-charts`.

Comment: Thanks Rafal! So the only choice here is to put all stuffs in a shell script.